# Google Action Webhook Implementation

Tags: node.js, webhooks, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

so I just started working on a project. I came across two different implementation of webhook for Google action agent. Can someone please explain, what is the difference between both?

Also which one is more extensible.

First one uses `actions-on-google` library,

```
'use strict';
 // Imports 
// ================================================================================================= 
const { dialogflow } = require('actions-on-google');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// Constants 
// ================================================================================================= 
// Instantiate the Dialogflow client with debug logging enabled.
const app = dialogflow({ debug: true });

// Intents  
// =================================================================================================
app.intent('welcome.intent', (conv) => {
conv.ask('Hello from webhook');
});

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

and second one uses `dialogflow-fulfillment`,

```
`'use strict'`;

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { WebhookClient } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
    console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
    console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

    function welcome(agent) {
        agent.add(`Hello from webhook agent`);
    }

    let intentMap = new Map();
    intentMap.set('welcome.intent', welcome);
    agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Both libraries are valid and supported by Google. Which one you use depends on what your goals are.

The `actions-on-google` library is best if your goal is **only** to develop Actions. It has support for some of the more advanced functions supported by the AoG platform, but does not support the other platforms that Dialogflow supports.

The `dialogflow-fulfillment` library is best if you want to **support multiple bot platforms** using Dialogflow (possibly including the Actions on Google platform).